# How todo an incremental sequence with java in Apache-Spark 2.x

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

How TODO an **incremental sequence** with **java** in **Apache-Spark 2.x** **DataFrame || TempTable** .

In other words what is the equivalent for **monotonically_increasing_id()** function in ApacheSpark->Sql->java   ||   API->Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Scala:

```
val dataFrame1 = dataFrame0.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id())
```

**with java**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
Daraset<Row> dataFrame1 = dataFrame0.withColumn("index",functions.monotonically_increasing_id());
```